# Firebase Cloud Functions - Post Request - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, express, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to post data to Firebase Cloud Functions. I use express.js and body-parser to receive the request. With Insomnia ( a REST client for API debugging), I have zero problems but with a VueJS HTTP request like

```
Vue.http.post("url", {private: false}, { 
           headers: {
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
           }
           }).then(res => {
               console.log(res);
           });
```

I got the error `Failed to load *url*: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `express`, you can use a package called [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). Basically what this error means is that you should allow clients to access your resource by saying "Hey, I know this client and I trust him, let him access what he needs". You can do it in the following way (from the `cors` docs):

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```